# What are the positions in `free` called?

Tags: linux, memory, sar

I am trying to compare the output of `free` with the output of `sar -r`:

```
# sar -r
12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
12:10:01 AM    629756  65293976     99.04    586536  60321636   5094176      7.49

# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      65923732    9120348   56803384          0     403628    5789524
-/+ buffers/cache:    2927196   62996536
Swap:      2097144          0    2097144
```

On the `free` line that begins `Mem:` it is obvious that we have what would be called in `sar`: *kbmemtotal*, *kbmemused*, *kbmemfree*, **???**, *kbbuffers*, *kbcached*.
On the line that begins `-/+`: **???**, **???**

**What are the names of the values that I've marked as *???*?** Is this the `kbcommit` value? I have read [Linux ate my ram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) which does explain what the numbers mean, but not their names. Also, the [free manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free) does not give the names either.

Answer (score 1):

The names actually match up, but `sar` and `free` don't show exactly the same fields.

Your first `???` isn't `kbcommit`, it's shared memory, the same as `Shmem` from `/proc/meminfo`.

The second row shows the memory usage if the memory used by buffers and cache was treated as free rather than used.

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      MemTotal  kbmemused  kbmemfree      Shmem  kbbuffers   kbcached
-/+ buffers/cache:      USED2      FREE2
Swap:            0          0          0
```

- MemTotal = MemTotal from /proc/meminfo
- Shmem = Shmem from /proc/meminfo
- USED2 = kbmemused - kbbuffers - kbcached
- FREE2 = kbmemfree + kbbuffers + kbcached

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as your output perhaps demonstrates, `sar`'s `kbmemused` is probably *not* the same as the second "Mem:" field from `free`.   From `man sar`:

> **kbmemused**           Amount  of used memory in kilobytes. *This does not take into account memory used by the
>                        kernel itself.*

Presuming that part of what's not taken into account is:

> **kbbuffers**
>                        Amount of memory used as buffers *by the kernel* in kilobytes.
>
> **kbcached**
>                        Amount of memory used to cache data *by the kernel* in kilobytes.

Hopefully this is not just a case of misleading documentation; I'm not a `sar` user.  In any case, the top line in `free` does include buffers and cache.  The second line (`+/- buffers/cache`) does not.  Notice 403628 (`buffers`) + 5789524 (`cached`) = 6193152, and 9120348 (`Mem: used`) - 6193152 = 2927196 (`+/- buffers/cache: used`).

> their names

You can call them whatever you want.  The names from `sar` are arbitrary.  If you refer to a value output from `free` as "memory used minus cache", it's obvious you mean the first number on the second line, etc.

Comment: The values from `sar` and from `free` were not taken at the same time.

Comment: Makes sense -- I used "*perhaps* demonstrates" since they don't clearly mesh with anything, but that is what the man page implies.  If you do look at them at the same time it should be easy to tell.

Comment: Yeah, would be better to do `sar -r 1 1; free` to compare them.

Comment: `kbmemused` *is* the same as the `Mem` `used` cell in the `free` output.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Is it inaccurate?

Comment: Yes, the first paragraph is wrong, as I said in the comment above.